# Use table manager in modeler in qgis

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, attribute-table, qgis-modeler

I need to reorder the fields in a tab file from within QGIS modeler. Table Manager plugin allows this but I can't seem to find a way to do this in modeler. It needs to be run on thousands of files.

Can we import/use plugins like table manager in the graphical-modeler or in the python window?

---

@Olle - I don't see the same options. How do I add them to my toolbox? They are active in processing-->options

[image: Active in processing option]

[image: My processing modeler]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the graphical modeller you have the opportunity to refactor fields wihtin a vector layer.

[image: refactor table of vector layer]

There you can reorder fields like in the table Manager plugin.  In a second step you could use this model with `processing.runalg("modeler:youmodelname", inputlayer, outputlayer)`in the console to iterate trough all desired files.

Comment: thanks but I don't see these tools. See edits to the question.

Comment: Hello GeorgeC, run  `processing.alglist("refactor")` in the python console and see whether the algorithm is available, registered correctly. This might be a Installation or Version Problem. I used QGIS 2.8 for the above example.

Comment: @GeorgeC - Looking at your screenshot in your question, I think your _Processing Toolbox_ is using the **Simplified interface**. You can see this at the very bottom of the toolbox, click on it to change it to **Advanced interface**. "Refactor" should be in the list now. otherwise it may be a versioning issue as @OlleOnkel mentioned. Also his tip of searching for it in the Python Console is good advice, just remember to use `import processing` first :)

Comment: @Joseph thanks...I was trying to find this in the Graphical Modeler...once you change the processing toolbox to advanced the graphical modeler also reflects this.

Comment: I'm not able to find this tool, either. I've searched for it in the python console in QGIS 2.8 and 2.12, but only get a NameError message. I have the "Advanced interface" option selected, as well. Any thoughts on what I'm missing? Thanks